# random Java буквы

Tags: java, случайные-числа

как выводит на экран 7 случайных букв через консоль.
допустим пишем через консоль:  Privet kak dela, segodnya pogoda xoroshaya.
И из этой строки выбрал 7 случайных букв.

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Случайный индекс буквы можете получить? Букву по этому индексу можете получить? 7 раз это проделать можете?

Answer (score 1):

1. Берете массив длиной равной цельной строке
2. Заполняете массив числами от 0 до длины строки-1
3. Применяете функцию перемешивания данных в этом массиве (любая, какая есть на свете)
4. Пробегаетесь циклом от 0 до 7 по массиву и берете из строки один элемент, начиная со значения, указанному под индексом цикла. (например `str.substring(arr[i], 1)`)

---

1 и 2 пункт можно заменить банально разбив указанную строку на массив символов. Тогда останется просто перемешать данные и взять первые 7 элементов массива

Comment: @denisKrivorutchko что это? И зачем?

Answer (score 0):

А еще проще:

```
List<Character> list = Arrays.asList(scanner.nextLine().split("").replaceAll(' ', '' );
list.shuffle;
System.out.println (list.subList(0, 7));
Либо если пробелы неконтролируюмые то вместо пробела "\\s+"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) { // считывать ввод будем сканнепром
    String input = sc.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", ""); // считываем ввод
    String preparedInput = input.replaceAll(" ", ""); // убираем пробелы
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(preparedInput.split("")); // создаем список
    Collections.shuffle(list); // перемешиваем список
    System.out.println(list.subList(0, 7)); // печатаем первые 7 элементов
}
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin добавил комментарии к коду

Comment: полистайте примеры ответов, посмотрите, чего в вашем не хватает по сравнению с ними: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa